# Using AsNoTracking, how to check eagerly loaded navigation properties for null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Using ASP.NET Core 2.1, consider the following code:

```
var customer = await db.Customers
                  .Include(x => x.Address)
                  .Where(x => x.CustomerId == user.CustomerId)
                  .AsNoTracking()
                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

When I try to check if the customer's Address is `null`,

```
if (customer.Address != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

and an Address does not exist for that customer, then I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning: ...

However, if the address exists (i.e. it's **not** `null`), then everything works fine.

Is there a proper way to check if an eagerly loaded navigational property has been found and still use `AsNoTracking`?

Comment: Apparently lazy-loading isn't supported for NoTracking querieshttps://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13173

Comment: I believe to resolve this you will need to apply an include.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data